# Allow form submission to server inside of angularJS?

Tags: forms, angularjs

According to the AngularJS doc's https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

"For this reason, Angular prevents the default action (form submission to the server) unless the  element has an action attribute specified."

is there any way to stop angularJS doing this?

Comment: `unless the element has an action` ...seems pretty obvious from the docs, give it an action

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the form submission to go down the browser handled route don't put the action attribute on the form use the directive ng-submit which basically calls a method on your controller which will allow you to send the data to the server via a xhr request.

Comment: Then put the action attribute on the form and don't use the ng-submit directive.

Comment: yeah pulling apart all of the forms in the CMS I'm using isn't really a option so I've gone for a directive:

Comment: .directive('form', ['$location', function($location) {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    priority: 999,
    compile: function() {
    return {
      pre: function(scope, element, if (attrs.noaction === '') return;
                    if (attrs.action === undefined || attrs.action === ''){
                        attrs.action = $location.absUrl();
                        console.log(element);
                        element.addClass('fadeing');
                        attrs.class = "standard-form";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]);

Comment: @vimes1984 if issue is related only to what CMS does, can always remove the action and recompile or just use `preventDefault()` yourself

Comment: the above directive does what i need to if someone wants to put it in a answer i'll accept it

Comment: You could answer yourself get your rep up :-)